# Difference between filter and filter_by in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Could anyone explain the difference between `filter` and `filter_by` functions in SQLAlchemy?
Which one should I be using?

Answer (score 543, accepted):

`filter_by` is used for simple queries on the column names using regular kwargs, like

`db.users.filter_by(name='Joe')`

The same can be accomplished with `filter`, not using kwargs, but instead using the '==' equality operator, which has been overloaded on the db.users.name object:

`db.users.filter(db.users.name=='Joe')`

You can also write more powerful queries using `filter`, such as expressions like:

`db.users.filter(or_(db.users.name=='Ryan', db.users.country=='England'))`

Comment: How does this work under the hood? Would not `db.users.name=='Ryan'` evaluate once to a constant and then be meaningless from then on? It seems like one would need to use a lambda for this to work.

Comment: the equality operator is overloaded

Comment: `type(model.column_name == 'asdf')` → `sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression`

Comment: Be careful when using `.filter`. a query like `id=12345`, `query(users).filter(id == id)` will not filter on `users.id`. Instead, it will evaluate `id == id` as `True` and return all users. You need to use `.filter(users.id == id)` (as demoed above). I made this mistake earlier today.

Answer (score 140):

We actually had these merged together originally, i.e. there was a "filter"-like method that accepted `*args` and `**kwargs`, where you could pass a SQL expression or keyword arguments (or both).  I actually find that a lot more convenient, but people were always confused by it, since they're usually still getting over the difference between `column == expression` and `keyword = expression`.  So we split them up.

Comment: I think your point about `column == expression` vs. `keyword = expression` is the key point to make about the difference between `filter` and `filter_by`. Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice related question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506105/flask-sqlalchemy-query-with-keyword-as-variable].

Comment: I'm new to sqlalchemy so excuse me if this is a stupid question, but filter_by() doesn't seem to allow for even the very simple conditions such as "price >= 100". So, why have filter_by() function anyway, if you only can use it for the very simplest condition such as "price = 100"?

Comment: because people like it

Comment: Is there any performance difference between them? I was thinking that `filter_by` might be a bit faster than `filter`.

Comment: The point of using `filter_by` is to be able to write jut the field name, for that class, no questions asked - while `flter` requires the actual column object - which usually will require one to type (and to read) at least a redundant class name.  So, if one wants to filter by  equality, it is rather convenient.

Comment: I like `filter_by` for building convenience functions into an app, which allow users to run simple queries by just passing in a table name and dictionary of equality filters.  Beyond this, though, it's difficult to see why I wouldn't just use `filter`.

Comment: Sometime filter_by is trick, eg. filter_by(customer.created_time < some_time) it cannot select the correct value, for some reason, the `<` always got true.

Answer (score 71):

It is a syntax sugar for faster query writing. Its implementation in pseudocode:

```
def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
    return self.filter(sql.and_(**kwargs))
```

For AND you can simply write:

```
session.query(db.users).filter_by(name='Joe', surname='Dodson')
```

btw

```
session.query(db.users).filter(or_(db.users.name=='Ryan', db.users.country=='England'))
```

can be written as

```
session.query(db.users).filter((db.users.name=='Ryan') | (db.users.country=='England'))
```

Also you can get object directly by PK via `get` method:

```
Users.query.get(123)
# And even by a composite PK
Users.query.get(123, 321)
```

When using `get` case its important that object can be returned without database request from `identity map` which can be used as cache(associated with transaction)

Comment: These code examples are misleading: Declarative base table classes and instances have neither filter nor query methods; they use the session.

Comment: I reproduce `users.filter` from previous answer. And may be its my fault :)
`query` attribute is [query_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=query_property#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.query_property) and its quite a standard sugar nowadays

Answer (score 43):

`filter_by` uses keyword arguments, whereas `filter` allows pythonic filtering arguments like `filter(User.name=="john")`

Answer (score 9):

Apart from all the technical information posted before, there is a significant difference between *filter()* and *filter_by()* in its usability.

The second one, *filter_by()*, may be used only for filtering by something specifically stated - a string or some number value. So it's usable only for category filtering, not for expression filtering.

On the other hand *filter()* allows using comparison expressions (==, <, >, etc.) so it's helpful e.g. when 'less/more than' filtering is needed. But can be used like *filter_by()* as well (when == used).

Just to remember both functions have different syntax for argument typing.