# sql alchemy filter results on properties of joined models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relation

I have a model X and a model Y.

Y contains a foreign key reference to X.id, with a instance of the related X entry available by the property x.

```
x_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('xtable.id'))    
x = relationship('X')
```

X also has a boolean property 'publish'.

Executing a query on Y, how can i filter my results to those where x.publish is True;

Ive tried doing something like this:

```
DBSession.query(Y).filter_by(x.publish = True).all()
```

But this doesnt work, i get an error saying keyword cant be an expression. Ive looked through the sql alchemy docs for a solution, but i cant seem to find what im looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `join` in your query to class `X` and use `filter` instead of `filter_by`:

```
qry = DBSession.query(Y)
qry = qry.join(X)
qry = qry.filter(X.publish == True)
qry.all()
```

or in one go:

```
DBSession.query(Y).join(X).filter(X.publish == True).all()
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy) regarding the difference between using `filter` and `filter_by`.

Answer (score 3):

Other option is

You can create direct new relationship

Like

```
x1 = relationship(X,
             primaryjoin='and_(X.id==Y.x_id, X.publish==True)'
             )
```

This will do join automatically.

Comment: you can now use this relationship directly by calling `self.x1`