# Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, case-insensitive

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy to query from a database of users; however, while

```
user = models.User.query.filter_by(username="ganye").first()
```

will return

```
<User u'ganye'>
```

doing

```
user = models.User.query.filter_by(username="GANYE").first()
```

returns

```
None
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to query the database in a case insensitive way, so that the second example will still return

```
<User u'ganye'>
```

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You can do it by using either the `lower` or `upper` functions in your filter:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
user = models.User.query.filter(func.lower(User.username) == func.lower("GaNyE")).first()
```

Another option is to do searching using `ilike` instead of `like`:

```
.query.filter(Model.column.ilike("ganye"))
```

Comment: Would this make the query slower compared to the `filter_by` method where the username column is indexed?

Answer (score 21):

Improving on @plaes's answer, this one will make the query shorter if you specify just the column(s) you need:

```
user = models.User.query.with_entities(models.User.username).\
filter(models.User.username.ilike("%ganye%")).all()
```

The above example is very useful in case one needs to use Flask's jsonify for AJAX purposes and then in your javascript access it using **data.result**:

```
from flask import jsonify
jsonify(result=user)
```

Comment: @VedranŠego I have seen the link, thanks for the reference. I will also perform my own test.

Answer (score 12):

you can do

```
user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(func.lower(User.username)==func.lower("GANYE")).first()
```

Or you can use ilike function

```
 user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(User.username.ilike("%ganye%")).first()
```

Comment: The second option shouldn't have percentages

Comment: did you mean filter() instead of filter_by()? I thought filter_by() takes keywords, not expressions, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution would be

```
func.lower(User.username).contains(username.lower())
```

It will produce sql like

```
WHERE (lower(user.username) LIKE '%%' || %s || '%%')
```

This means your db `username` will be converted to the lower case and your python value `username` also will be converted to lower case. So now you do not have to worry about the case sesitivity

If your `username` is `Sara Smith` It will work for `ara`, `sar`, `Sara` or event `a S`

Comment: For those who are wondering, do make the import as `from sqlalchemy.sql import func` to get the aforementioned `func`.

Answer (score 2):

If it fits your use case, you may consider setting a custom [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) on the column, such that the column automatically handles comparisons in a case-insensitive manner.

It's worth noting:

- the collation will apply to all queries on the column
- the collation will apply to `ORDER BY` clauses as well
- a collation may be specified directly in queries, rather than  being defined on the column

  - this may potentially incur performance penalties
- collation definitions tend to be RDBMS / locale / language-specific - consult the relevant documentation
- collation names may not be portable between different RDBMS
- available collation attributes may vary by RDBMS

in other words, consult your RDBMS's docs before using this feature.

This example script shows how you might use collations for MySQL, Postgresql (note the special-casing) and Sqlite; each RDBMS returns all three possible results for the query value.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

data = {
    'mysql': ('mysql:///test', 'utf8mb4_general_ci'),
    'postgresql': ('postgresql:///test', 'coll'),
    'sqlite': ('sqlite://', 'NOCASE'),
}


for dialect, (uri, collation) in data.items():
    Base = orm.declarative_base()

    class Test(Base):
        __tablename__ = 't16573095'

        id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = sa.Column(sa.String(32, collation=collation))

    engine = sa.create_engine(uri, echo=False, future=True)
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)

    if dialect == 'postgresql':
        # Postgres collations are more complicated
        # - read the docs!
        with engine.begin() as conn:
            conn.execute(sa.text('DROP COLLATION IF EXISTS coll'))
            stmt = """CREATE COLLATION coll (provider='icu', locale='und-u-ks-level2', deterministic=false)"""
            conn.execute(sa.text(stmt))

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, future=True)

    with Session.begin() as s:
        instances = [Test(name=name) for name in ['GANYE', 'ganye', 'gAnYe']]
        s.add_all(instances)

    with Session() as s:
        results = s.execute(sa.select(Test.name).where(Test.name == 'GaNyE')).scalars()
        print(f'{dialect:-<12}')
        for name in results:
            print(name)
        print('-' * 12)
```

To specify a collation in a query, use an attribute's [collate](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html?highlight=collate#sqlalchemy.orm.QueryableAttribute.collate) method:

```py
with Session() as s:
    query = sa.select(Test).where(Test.name.collate('coll') == 'GaNyE')
    results = s.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

For declarative users, the equivalent without using `query` is the [ColumnOperators.ilike](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.ilike) method:

```py
class User(DeclarativeBase):
    username: str

req = select(User).where(User.username.ilike("GANYE"))
result = session.execute(req)
```

will render as `lower(User.username) LIKE lower("GANYE")`

This is still the case in SQLAlchemy 2.0, and is compatible with `AsyncSession`, for those using it.

Comment: The method hasn't changed in 2.0 - it was exactly the same in [earlier releases](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.ilike)

Comment: Many thanks and good catch, I've updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

- By one field

  ```py
  uname = "ganye"
  user = models.User.query.filter(User.username.ilikef(f"%{uname}%").first()
  ```
- By several fields

  ```py
  return db.session.query(Post).filter(
      Post.title.ilike(f"%{search_query}%")
      | Post.body.ilike(f"%{search_query}%")
  )
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use **case insensitive** **contains** function ie: **.icontains()**. Example:

```py
.query.filter(Model.column.icontains("search_query"))
```

cause you are not sure if the user is going to provide the exact text you want to compare with, so using **icontains** will return a result(s) even if the user query does not contain the **EXACT** word or phrase he/she is searching for.

Comment: But the OP _does_ want an exact match, apart from the case.