# How to use the filter operater of like in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to query data from database use sqlalchemy, and the code is below:

```
    session.query(Person).filter(Person.name.like("%tom%")).all()
```

but this is case sensitive, in other words, the params of like is just match "tom" and dose not contain "TOM". How to deal with the query without case sensitive ?

Comment: Look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlalchemy's built-in  [ilike](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.ilike).

e.g

```
select([sometable]).where(sometable.c.column.ilike("%foobar%"))
```

ILIKE is quasi-standard, it is supported by MySQL and PostgresQL.

Comment: session.query(Person).filter(Person.name.ilike("%tom%")).all() seems to to be ok.