# PostgreSQL ILIKE query with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to run a query that selects all posts, case insensitive, that have titles that match `'%' + [some_phrase] + '%'`. That is, select all rows that have titles that *contain* some phrase, case insensitive. From the research I've done, it looks like I need to use Postgres's ILIKE query for it to match case insensitive. How can I execute a query like this with SQLAlchemy?

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    content = db.Column(db.String(5000))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think it should work

```
Post.query.filter(Post.title.ilike('%some_phrase%'))
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=ilike#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.ilike

Comment: Does this affect performance compared to the more restricted `like()` function?

Comment: It depends on an engine you use: PostgreSQL, MySQL or else. 
SQLAlchemy is just a wrapper for SQL.

Answer (score 26):

For python 3.6 instead of `'%' + some_phrase + '%'` you can write

```
Post.query.filter(Post.title.ilike(f'%{some_phrase}%'))
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another workable solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.operators import ilike_op
Post.query.filter(ilike_op(Post.title, f'%{some_phrase}%'))
```

This solution helped me to overcame the warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'ilike' for class 'property'` when I used `hybrid_property`