# How to have a 'broad filter' in SQLAlchemy query search

Tags: python, regex, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model called Report, and want to search with a country filter. 
Suppose the database has saved the data like "India", "Pakistan", etc.

```
queries = db.session.query(Report).filter_by(country=country_name)
```

Is there any way I could filter the search of country_name to look for india, INDIA, etc.
?

The only possibility I could think of is converting the 'country_name' variable to the correct format and then hitting the search. But is there a way to search by a Regex or something?

Excuse my ignorance, as I have just started with Python

Comment: Are asking about this: [Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ilike`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.ilike) operator

```
db.session.query(Report).filter(Report.country.ilike("india"))
```

This is a case insensitive `LIKE` statement.