# Why use SqlAlchemy's func.lower(mystring) vs. mystring.lower()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Look at this answer: [Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query)

Why is it better to use SQLAlchemy's `func.lower(mystring)` instead of python's native `mystring.lower()`?

Comment: It probably doesn't do much on a string literal, but it does make a difference in that you can use it on a column:  `func.lower(SomeModel.some_column)`

Answer (score 9):

The context is important.

```
user = models.User.query.filter(func.lower(User.username) == func.lower("GaNyE")).first()
```

Here, there is no string with a `lower` method to call; you are composing a SQL command to execute in the database. `func.lower` doesn't return a lowercase string; it returns an object that represents SQL code that can be used to produce a lowercase string.

---

As mgilson points out, there's no need to use `func.lower` on actual Python values; they are constant for each row the filter will be applied against, but I'm not sure SQLAlchemy is able to detect and optimize such situations. Either of the following

```
user = models.User.query.filter(func.lower(User.username) == "ganye").first()
user = models.User.query.filter(func.lower(User.username) == "GaNyE".lower()).first()
```

would produce SQL code like `lower(username) = :lower_1` instead of `lower(username) = lower(:lower_1)`, which can make the SQL query more efficient by eliminating a call to `lower` for each line.

Comment: The second `func.lower('GaNyE')` probably doesn't buy you much above `'ganye'` or `'GaNyE'.lower()`, does it?  It seems to me that it would only be useful as an operation on the column...

Comment: Right. Constants are converted to bind parameters, so you end up with `lower(:1)` instead of `(:1)`. I don't know if SQLAlchemy can recognize that the same value is always passed to `lower` and optimize the resulting code, so it would be better to lowercase the string in Python first in that case.