# SQLAlchemy and multi-column case-insensitive query

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

Assuming we have a table consisting of column_1, column_2, ... , column_n and all of them are string fields. The conditions we are going to do case-insensitive query are stored in a dictionary d like d[column_1] = "Hello", which may or may not contains all columns. How can we do the query?

I checked the question [Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query). It contains a lot of awesome answers, but none of them works if we do not know what conditions we have until runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to build the query looping through each key of the dictionary.

As you didn't give any code sample, I'm going to call the table model class `TableModel` and each column will be `column_1`, `column_2`, etc.

Something like this should work:

```
d = {'column_1': 'some_string', 'column_3': 'another_string'}
# skipping 'column_2' just to exemplify how every column is optional in the dictionary

my_query = TableModel.query

for k in d:
    my_query = my_query.filter(getattr(TableModel, k).ilike(d[k]))
```

And that's about it. Afterwards you can use `my_query` as any other query, e.g., `my_query.count()` or `my_query.all()`

Comment: You should use `getattr(TableModel, k)` instead of `eval`.