# How to ignore case when filter value in database with python

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, ignore-case

I've tried to find an answer of my question.

And I find some answers but I don't know how to apply those to my question.

I'm using flask sqlalchemy.

This is my python code for getting product list.

```
def get_products(cls, request):
    with gshop.session_scope() as session:

        products = session.query(Product.id,
                                 Product.product_name,
                                 Product.logo_img_id,
                                 Product.product_cat_id,
                                 Product.display_no,
                                 Product.brand_id)

        if 'query' in request:
            query = json.loads(request['query'])
            filters = query['filters']
            for key, value in filters.items():
                try:
                    products = products.filter(getattr(Product, key).like("%" + str(value) + "%"))
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
```

'request' parameter is the 'param' from http request of client.

`print(request)` looks like this.

```
{
    'query': '{
        "filters":{
            "product_name":"aBcDeFgH"
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to search product by name 'aBcDeFgH',

I want to get all data which includes this keyword with ignoring case.

How can I do this?

If you have any link or idea, just throw that to me.

Then I'll try a new way with referenced.

Thanks in advance, and Happy New Year. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry for my googling ability..

This was a kind of simple thing.

[Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573690/8481089)

This link gave a perfect answer for this silly question.

Here's an solution sample.

**Original code**

```
products = products.filter(getattr(Product, key).like("%" + str(value) + "%"))
```

**Solved code**

```
products = products.filter(getattr(Product, key).ilike("%" + str(value) + "%"))
```

Only just change `like` to `ilike`.