# Flask-Restless case-insensitive query

Tags: flask-restless

How to make case-insensitive search query using Flask-Restless?

## Example:

```
api/user?q={"filters":[{"name":"lastname","op":"like","val":"%davidson%"}]}
```

I would like the previous code to return "davidson", "Davidson", "DAVIDSON"...
But it only returns "davidson".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ilike` operator like so:

```
api/user?q={"filters":[{"name":"lastname","op":"ilike","val":"davidson"}]}
```

This is not really documented in the Flask-Restless docs, but the operator is documented in SQLAlchemy which is the OR mapper Flask-Restless uses under the hood. See the relevant docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.ilike) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573690/5730444).