# How to handle symbols (*, +, ~,...) in sqlalchemy on a flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a full web-page working and now I am debugging the errors. Until now, the only one I can't get rid of is when the input on my web-page introduces a symbol (+, *, ~,...)

If I change the operator: op('~* ') for a like, it works but I don't need the like operator, I need the case insensitive op('~* ')

```
# first, i take from my web the filter that an user have introduced
filter_tag = str(request.form.get('filter_tag'))
if take_filter.filter_tag != '':
    conditions.append(clothes.c.column_tag==filter_tag)

query = session.query(clothes).filter(and_(*conditions),).distinct(clothes.c.nummer).order_by(clothes.c.nummer)
```

It works perfectly with a normal text but if the user introduces a sign (*, ~, +,...) it returns an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the code that you need to work, not some other code that's only vaguely related to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it based on this post: [Case insensitive with a equal operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query) , the main difference is that I need to check if a value of a column contains a string and on the other post is a equal relation (==).

For that, I changed the filtering from op('~*') to contains. But, contains works on a case sensitive way and to fix this I just put in both lower funtion.

```
#import the upper and lower function from sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import func

#take the filter from browser
filter_tag = str(request.form.get('filter_tag'))

#Check that the filter is not empty
if take_filter.filter_tag != '':
    conditions.append(func.lower(clothes.c.column_tag).contains(func.lower(filter_tag)))

query = session.query(clothes).filter(and_(*conditions)).distinct(clothes.c.nummer).order_by(clothes.c.nummer)
```