# How to remove a row from a query result set in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I need a function that does something like:

```
query = Member.query.filter(Member.age > 3)
query = filter_query(query)

def filter_query(query):
    for q in query:
        if not q.someAttr == "someValue":
            query.remove(q) # <-- this doesn't work. is there anything similar?
    return query
```

Please, don't ask why I need this. It's a long story )

UPDATE

I decided to use maybe not the most beautiful but still a solution that works for now.

```
query = Member.query.filter(Member.age > 3)
query = filter_query(query)

def filter_query(query):
    id_list = []
    for q in query:
        if q.someAttr == "someValue":
            id_list.append(q.id)
    return Member.query.filter(Member.id.in_(id_list))
```

Comment: `query.delete()?`

Comment: Thanks for the idea but didn't work )

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Valid strategies for session synchronization are 'evaluate', 'fetch', False`

Comment: Would it be OK to bring the query results into a list of dicts & then delete the dicts you don't want?

Comment: Yes, but how to convert it back to BaseQuery object? I have no idea.

Comment: This question confuses me.  The requirement _seems_ to be to remove an item from a query's results on the client side, but the solution in the update involves calling `filter` on the query, which will execute another query on the database.  But if we are going to query the database anyway, why not just apply `filter(Model.someAttr == 'somevalue')` to the original query?

Comment: As pointed out by @snakecharmerb, `for q in query:` executes the query (adding another `filter()` doesn't in itself), so you're running it twice.

Comment: In my case, filter doesn't work, because of SQLite database that contains data in cyrillic. This is a real pain ) 
And hybrid_method doesn't work either. That's why I need to loop BaseQuery object and remove some objects from it and return BaseQuery object. Thanks )

Comment: "filter doesn't work, because of SQLite database that contains data in cyrillic" - can you elaborate on this?  I didn't think sqlite had any limitations for unicode (except maybe case-insensitive matching).

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs with case insensitive `like` query )
Unfortunately, I can't find the page that I found a few days ago, where it's said something like "supporting case insensitive querying of cyrillic text would double the size of SQLite file"

Comment: That's unlucky :(  So the problem is: You retrieve a list of model instances, you perform the equivalent of a case-insensitive `like`, in python, and now you specifically need to transform the filtered results back into a `query` object because you need perform further filter/grouping/ordering in the database?

Comment: Exactly ) I was surprised to know nothing like `remove()`, `delete()`, `del` can remove an object from BaseQuery object.

Comment: The trouble is, the values aren't there to be tested until the `query` is executed, and at that point you no longer have a `query`, just a list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a query must be run in Sqlite which includes an `ILIKE` filter on non-ASCII text, but the [default Sqlite build does not support case-insensitive matching on such text](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q18).

One possible workaround is to store a case-normalised copy of the text in another column.  This assumes that doubling the storage for the text is not an issue.

A simple way to do this would look like this:

```
class Likeable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'likeable'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(32))
    lowercase_name = sa.Column(sa.String(32))
```

Instances can be created like this:

```
likeable = Likeable(name='Россия', lowercase_name='россия')
```

and queried like this

```
session.query(Likeable).filter(Likeable.lowercase_name.like('р%'))
```

This is ok, but requires that `name` and `lowercase_name` are always updated simultaneously.  We can get around this by masking `lowercase_name` with a [hybrid property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html?highlight=hybrid#), and intercepting assignments to `name` with an [attribute listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.set).  The listener detects when `name` is modified and passes the new value to `lowercase_name`'s setter.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


Base = declarative_base()


class Likeable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'likeable'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(32))
    _lowercase_name = sa.Column(sa.String(32))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Likeable(name='{self.name}', lowercase_name='{self.lowercase_name}')"

    @hybrid_property
    def lowercase_name(self):
        return self._lowercase_name

    @lowercase_name.setter
    def lowercase_name(self, value):
        # str.casefold is preferred over str.lower for case-insensitive matching
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold
        self._lowercase_name = value.casefold()


@sa.event.listens_for(Likeable.name, 'set')
def receive_set(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.lowercase_name = value
```

Running this code:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

session = Session(bind=engine)
likeables = [Likeable(name=n) for n in ['Россия', 'Русский', 'Французский']]
session.add_all(likeables)
session.commit()
session.close()

session = Session(bind=engine)
q = session.query(Likeable).filter(Likeable.lowercase_name.like('р%'))
for r in q:
    print(r)
session.close()
```

Produces this output:

```
Likeable(name='Россия', lowercase_name='россия')
Likeable(name='Русский', lowercase_name='русский')
```

This is demonstration code.  For production, you would want to add checks to ensure that `name` and `lowercase_name` can't get out of sync.

Comment: Great! I'll check it as soon as possible. There is another problem: the SQLlite file, in my case, is generated by mdb-export that exports data from MDB file. I'll see how it works in my project. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A neater approach might be to [use a case-insensitive collation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70794113/5320906).