# Trying to make a query case insensitive in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How could I make this query be case insensitive?

```
result = db.session.query(countries).filter_by(name=country,capital=capital).first()
```

Im using Flask SQL-Alchemy by the way. I can do **db.func.lower()** but I havent found a way to use it properly in my line yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `filter` instead of `filter_by`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

result = db.session.query(countries).filter(
   func.lower(countries.name) == name.lower(),
   func.lower(countries.capital) == capital.lower()
).first()
```

If `countries` is a table (not model) you should use `countries.c.name` syntax.

Similar topic: [Case Insensitive Flask-SQLAlchemy Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573095/case-insensitive-flask-sqlalchemy-query).

Comment: thanks alot for the answer! you were correct. im using a table btw! so using the syntax your showed made it work. btw, in your code there is filter_by. this is the code that ended up working for me: `result = db.session.query(countries).filter(
            db.func.lower(countries.c.name) == country.lower(),
            db.func.lower(countries.c.capital) == capital.lower()
            ).first()`

Comment: IT was typo and mistake of . Corrected