# flask sqlalchemy query with keyword as variable

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hometown = db.Column(db.String(140))
    university = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

To get a list of users from New York, this is my query:

```
User.query.filter_by(hometown='New York').all()
```

To get a list of users who go to USC, this is my query:

```
User.query.filter_by(university='USC').all()
```

And to get a list of users from New York, and who go to USC, this is my query:

```
User.query.filter_by(hometown='New York').filter_by(university='USC').all()
```

Now, I would like to dynamically generate these queries based on the value of a variable.

For example, my variable might look like this:

```
    {'hometown': 'New York'}
```

Or like this:

```
    {'university': 'USC'}
```

... Or even like this:

```
    [{'hometown': 'New York'}, {'university': 'USC'}]
```

Can you help me out with writing a function which takes a dictionary (or list of dictionaries) as an input, and then dynamically builds the correct sqlalchemy query?

If I try to use a variable for the keyword, I get this err:

```
key = 'university'
User.query.filter_by(key='USC').all()

InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'User'>' has no property 'key'
```

Secondly, I am not sure how to chain multiple filter_by expressions together dynamically.

I can explicitly, call out a filter_by expression, but how do I chain several together based on a variable?

Hope this makes more sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, we can help you build that function. What is the problem you're running into when you try to build it yourself?

Comment: When trying to assign a variable (example: kv = 'hometown') as a keyword arg, I get this error: nvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'User'>' has no property 'kv'

Comment: Can you show that code as part of the question? As it is, your question seems to show what you know, rather than asking for an explanation for what you are trying to have answered.

Comment: got it ... adding more now. thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe you can pass a single dictionary (not a list of dictionaries) directly into `filter_by`.  So `dict = {'hometown': 'New York', 'university': 'USC'}` and `User.query.filter_by(dict).all()`.  I am not positive on this, however.

Comment: when i pass a dictionary to filter_by ( example: {'university: 'USC'} ), i get this err: TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's [`filter_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) takes keyword arguments:

> filter_by(**kwargs)

In other words, the function will allow you to give it any keyword parameter. This is why you can use any keyword that you want in your code: SQLAlchemy basically sees the arguments a dictionary of values. See the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) for more information on keyword arguments.

So that allows the developers of SQLAlchemy to *receive* an arbitrary bunch of keyword arguments in a dictionary form. But you're asking for the opposite: can you *pass* an arbitrary bunch of keyword arguments to a function?

It turns out that in Python you can, using a feature called [*unpacking*](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Simply create the dictionary of arguments and pass it to the function preceded by `**`, like so:

```
kwargs = {'hometown': 'New York', 'university' : 'USC'}
User.query.filter_by(**kwargs)
# This above line is equivalent to saying...
User.query.filter_by(hometown='New York', university='USC')
```

Comment: how do you implement "in_" by doing this ?

Comment: @Ricky Unfortunately I haven't used SQLAlchemy in awhile, so I don't know off the top of my head. You might be better off asking a new question.

Answer (score 3):

`filter_by(**request.args)` doesn't work well if you have non-model query parameters, like `page` for pagination, otherwise you get errors like these:

```
InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.MyModelSerializable'>' has no property 'page'
```

I use something like this which ignores query parameters not in the model:

```
    builder = MyModel.query
    for key in request.args:
        if hasattr(MyModel, key):
            vals = request.args.getlist(key) # one or many
            builder = builder.filter(getattr(MyModel, key).in_(vals))
    if not 'page' in request.args:
        resources = builder.all()
    else:
        resources = builder.paginate(
            int(request.args['page'])).items
```

Considering a model with a column called `valid`, something like this will work:

```
curl -XGET "http://0.0.0.0/mymodel_endpoint?page=1&valid=2&invalid=whatever&valid=1"
```

`invalid` will be ignored, and `page` is available for pagination and best of all, the following SQL will be generated: `WHERE mymodel.valid in (1,2)`

(get the above snippet for free if you use this [boilerplate-saving module](https://github.com/opyate/flask_sandboy/blob/develop/flask_sandboy/service.py#L28))

Comment: does this work with nested properties? for example, product.category.name ? if not, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean where a category is foreign-keyed to a product? In that case, no :) There probably is a way to do it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @opyate that `filter_by(**request.args)` doesn't work well if you have non-model query parameters, like `page` for pagination, the following alternative can be used too:

Assuming that `page` is being taken in the form of `request.args.get()`, then:

```
def get_list(**filters):
    page = None
    if 'page' in filters:
        page = filters.pop('limit')
    items = Price.query.filter_by(**filters)
    if page is not None:
        items = items.paginate(per_page=int(page)).items
    else:
        items = items.all()
    return {
        "items": items
    }
```

and then the `get` function

```
def get(self):
    hometown = request.args.get('hometown')
    university = request.args.get('university')
    page = request.args.get('page')
    return get_list(**request.args)
```

I have tried implementing this on my flask application, and it works smoothly.

Of course, one drawback that can be is if there are multiple values like `page` that are not a part of the model, then each of them has to be defined separately in the `get_list`, but that can be done by list comprehension