# Flask - Convert request.args to dict

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to figure out how to pass the request.args to sqlalchemy filter.

I thought this should work:

```
model.query.filter(**request.args).all()
```

But it's throwing the error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userid'
```

When userid or any other get arg is present.

According to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506105/flask-sqlalchemy-query-with-keyword-as-variable - you can pass a dict to the filter function.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks :)

**UPDATE:** Many thanks to the poster below, however now it's throwing the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY tblclients.clientname' at line 3") 'SELECT favourites.id AS favourites_id, favourites.userid AS favourites_userid, favourites.clientid AS favourites_clientid, favourites.last_visit AS favourites_last_visit \nFROM favourites INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.clientid = favourites.clientid \nWHERE favourites.userid = %s ORDER BY tblclients.clientname' ([u'41'],)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

First, you have to use `filter_by`, not `filter`.

Second, Flask `request.args` uses a MultiDict, a dict with the values inside a list, allowing more than one value for the same key, because the same field can appear more than once in a querystring. You got the error because the SQL query got the `[u'41']` when it expected only `'41'`. You can use `request.args.to_dict()` to fix that:

```
model.query.filter_by(**request.args.to_dict()).all()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  And to add to it: using `request.args.to_dict()` is the correct while `dict(request.args)` is not because it will produce an dictionary whose values consist of lists.

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter_by`:

```
model.query.filter_by(**request.args).all()
```

`filter` is used like this: `query.filter(Class.property == value)` while `filter_by`  is used like this: `query.filter_by(property=value)` (the first one being an expression and the latter one being a keyword argument).

Answer (score 2):

`filter_by(**request.args)` doesn't work well if you have non-model query parameters, like `page` for pagination, otherwise you get errors like these:

```
InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.JobSerializable'>' has no property 'page'
```

I use something like this which ignores query parameters not in the model:

```
    builder = MyModel.query
    for key in request.args:
        if hasattr(MyModel, key):
            vals = request.args.getlist(key) # one or many
            builder = builder.filter(getattr(MyModel, key).in_(vals))
    if not 'page' in request.args:
        resources = builder.all()
    else:
        resources = builder.paginate(
            int(request.args['page'])).items
```

Considering a model with a column called `valid`, something like this will work:

```
curl -XGET "http://0.0.0.0/mymodel_endpoint?page=1&valid=2&invalid=whatever&valid=1"
```

`invalid` will be ignored, and `page` is available for pagination and best of all, the following SQL will be generated: `WHERE mymodel.valid in (1,2)`

(get the above snippet for free if you use this [boilerplate-saving module](https://github.com/opyate/flask_sandboy/blob/develop/flask_sandboy/service.py#L28))

Answer (score 1):

You can:

http://localhost:5000/filter-test?var=test

```
query_dict = request.args.to_dict()

print(query_dict)
{'var': 'test'}

print(query_dict['var'])
var
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.