# python: flask-sqlalchemy combine filter_by and _in

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Following the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506105/flask-sqlalchemy-query-with-keyword-as-variable) I have a little `flask` view that filters data based on querystring arguments:

```
@app.route('/regs')
def regs_data():

    #check what data is available
    #REGS is a sqlalchemy model
    cols = REGS.__table__.columns.keys()

    kwargs = {}
    for k, v in request.args.lists():
        if k not in cols:
            abort(400, "helpful err msg")

        #takes only first occurrence
        kwargs[k]=v[0]

    my_query = REGS.query.filter_by(**kwargs).all()

    #....modify the query data for return

    return the_data_as_json
```

This works great for when there is only 1 occurence of each key in `request.args`. How can I extend this to cope with multiple values for each keyword? e.g `/regs?foo=1&foo=2`

Is there a way to apply both `filter_by` and `in_()`

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use `filter_by()` and `in()` in a sequential way?

Comment: @RichArt using v instead of v[0] raises sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError

Comment: Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys. May be the answer of NPE helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/make-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is to iterate over each of the arguments and chain the filters together.

Not quite as neat but it works.

```
def regs_data():

    #get allowed data names
    cols = REGS.__table__.columns.keys()

    #make base query object
    my_query = REGS.query

    for k, v in request.args.lists():
        if k not in cols:
            abort(400, "helpful err msg")

        #chain together filters for each arg 
        my_query  = my_query.filter(getattr(REGS, k).in_(tuple(v)))

     #fire the query
     data = my_query.all()


    #....modify the query data for return

    return the_data_as_json
```