# How to make filtering on db in flask more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

**Flask beginner here**

I have a flask app that stores data in a db. I am trying to filter the db based on the user parameters like `country_code` or `price_type` etc.

Right now, I have multiple filter functions in `database.py` as follows:

```
class DatabaseService:

    @staticmethod
    def read_list():
        items = Price.query.all()
        return {
            "items": items
        }

    @staticmethod
    def filter_prices_cc(country_code):
        if country_code is not None:
            items = Price.query.filter(country_code == country_code)
        return {
            "items": items
        }

    @staticmethod
    def filter_prices_pt(price_type):
        if price_type is not None:
            items = Price.query.filter(price_type == price_type)
        return {
            "items": items
        }
```

and I am calling these methods in `controller.py` as follows:

```
@ns.route("/")
class Prices(Resource):
    def get(self):
        country = request.args.get('country_code')
        price_type = request.args.get('price_type')
        if country is not None:
            return DatabaseService.filter_prices_cc(country)
        if price_type is not None:
            return DatabaseService.filter_prices_pt(price_type)
        else:
            return DatabaseService.read_list()
```

Is there a more efficient way to change the filter methods so that depending on what the `request.args.get()`, the db is filtered? Something like: defining one filter method in `database.py` and this takes the values from `request.args.get()` and filters the data

I have to get the following scenarios:

1. If `country_code` is entered by the user, filter the db by it
2. If `price_type` is entered by the user, filter the db by it
3. If both `price_type` & `country_code` are entered by the user, filter the db by them combined
4. If none of them are entered, then the entire list of values has to be shown

**Sample data:**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": 21.4,
            "start": "2020-05-12T00:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T01:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": 18.93,
            "start": "2020-05-12T01:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T02:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "value": 18.06,
            "start": "2020-05-12T02:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T03:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "LU",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": 17.05,
            "start": "2020-05-12T03:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T04:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "TODAY"
        }]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way, but you can pass the values from `request.args.get()` as `**kwargs`:

The `database.py` would look as:

```
class DatabaseService:
    @staticmethod
    def read_list(**filters):
        items = Price.query.filter_by(**filters).all()
        return {
            "items": items
        }
```

and `controller.py` as:

```
@ns.route("/")
class Prices(Resource):
    def get(self):
        country = request.args.get('country_code')
        price_type = request.args.get('price_type')
        return DatabaseService.read_list(**request.args)
```

Based on if you have the `country_code` or `price_type`, the filtering should work

This might be interesting for you:

[flask sqlalchemy query with keyword as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506105/flask-sqlalchemy-query-with-keyword-as-variable)