# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Greater than or equal to

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a "greater than or equal to" comparison in a query.

I have a model field:

```
invoicedate = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=True, key='InvoiceDate')
```

And i'm trying to do the following filter:

```
Invoice.query.filter_by(invoicedate >= date.today()).count()
```

When I run the view, it keeps throwing the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'invoicedate' is not defined
```

What is the correct syntax for a greater than or equal filter in sqlalchemy or flask-sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You want `filter`, not `filter_by`:

```
Invoice.query.filter(Invoice.invoicedate >= date.today())
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy) for more on `filter` vs `filter_by`