# Why is my this flask-sqlalchemy query failing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a query which emits the stock data for a given ticker for the current day. My underlying model records the date and time in a datetime field. Currently, I am trying to query by ticker and then time_stamp.

```
@socketio.on("get initial data")
def on_initial_data(ticker):
    """
    Emits the initial stock data for given ticker.
    :param str ticker: ticker of stock to query.
    """

    socketio.emit("initial data",
                  [i.serialize for i
                   in Stock.query.filter_by(
                      ticker=ticker,
                      time_stamp=db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today()).order_by(Stock.time_stamp)],
                  room=request.sid)
```

When this is executed however, I get the error:

`HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I am not sure why I am getting this because isn't the `db.func.date()` casting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mixed `filter_by()` and `filter()`. See [What's the difference between filter and filter_by in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy) and [Flask-SQLAlchemy - Greater than or equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699756/flask-sqlalchemy-greater-than-or-equal-to). In short, you're comparing `time_stamp` for equality with an expression producing a boolean and the resulting query might look something like:

```
... WHERE ticker = :ticker AND time_stamp = (DATE(time_stamp) = :date) ...
```

Instead:

```
Stock.query.\
    filter_by(ticker=ticker).\
    filter(db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today()).\
    order_by(Stock.time_stamp)
```