# How to write select statement in sqlachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do the select statement in sqlachemy like

```
select user.id from user where user.name = 'test'
```

I loaded user table by:

```
User = Table('user',metadata,autoload=True)
Result = session.query(User.c.id).filter_by(name='test').first()
```

I got an error

"NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type "

Can you suggest how to carry out that SQL in sqlachemy ?

Comment: Why `User.c.id` and not `User.id`?

Comment: @fedorqui if it was User.id, i'd get "'Table' object has no attribute 'id'"

Comment: @alKid  i don't want to create a class for mapping into, just want to use Table object. And if you take more carefully in the link you give me, there is no reference of using query and filter clauses together.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
r =session.query(statSoftware.c.id).filter(statSoftware.c.name=='Apache').first()
```

Using `filter()` instead of `filter_by()`, Allows to get all needed columns .

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2128558/1982962) to understand the differences.

Comment: i've seen it, but filter_by(name='test') doesn't work in this case. can you suggest how to use filter_by in my case ?

Comment: There's no easy way to do this since you specified `statSoftware.c.id`. When you specify `filter_by`, it looks  at the last entity specified by a `query` or `join` function. You specified a column, however, not a table in your `query`. SQLAlchemy 0.9 (not yet officially released) has [`load_only`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#load-only-cols), which could make this easier. But really, I'd still just recommend using `filter`.