# getting multiple parameters from url using flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
import config
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
## app and db is defined on model.py
from model import db, app, PLAY_STORE
@app.route('/app-api', methods=['GET'])
def listapp():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        store=request.args.get('store')
        category=request.args.get('category')
        results = PLAY_STORE.query.filter_by(Store=store,Category=category).all()
        json_results = []
        for result in results:
          d = {'rank': result.Rank,
           'store': result.Store,
           'category': result.Category,
           'type': result.Type,
           'title': result.Title}
          json_results.append(d)

    return jsonify(items=json_results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am trying to build a rest api on top of mysql database using flask.
In the above program I am trying to get the store and category from the url. Even though I use `request.args.get`, Store value is empty,i.e json_results is empty.If I hard code making `PLAY_STORE.query.filter_by(Store="Play Store")` i am getting the expected output.But when i type `127.0.0.1/app-api?store="Play Store"`  json_results is  empty.

I have one more issue .How to put multiple conditions in the filter_by, something like `PLAY_STORE.query.filter_by(Store="Play Store" and Category="Games")`.

Comment: for one thing, you're not supposed to put spaces in urls. '%20' is used instead of spaces most of the time (stackoverflow uses hypens '-', as you can tell). So try 127.0.0.1/app-api?store="Play%20Store"

Comment: `filter_by` accepts `**kwargs`. So you can just comma separate key-value pairs, e.g. `PLAY_STORE.query.filter_by(Store="Play Store", Category="Games")`. Please avoid using capital letters in your variable names and read the [pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: thank you !!PLAY_STORE.query.filter_by(Store="Play Store",Category="games") is working

Comment: Play%20Store is not working

Comment: What is 'Store' value??, Can add this `print request.args.get('store')` and share the value

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/app-api?store='Play%20Store'&category='Games'

Comment: Store is a column in the table

Comment: am asking about what exactly you are exactly getting form url `request.args.get('store')` in your view

Comment: It is printing Play Store

Comment: try this **'http://127.0.0.1:5000/app-api?store=Play Store&category=Games`**

Comment: when i try printing store and category it prints Play Store and Games but when i use it in filter_by results is empty

Comment: the issue is you are appening **single quotes for `Play Store and Games`** . if you remove those those will work fine. copy url form my above comment that will work

Comment: any luck with this new url ???

Comment: 1127.0.0.1:5000/app-api?store=Play Store&category=Games is working thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your GET url parameters

Try this url:

```
  127.0.0.1:5000/app-api?store=Play Store&category=Games
```

You don't need to send single quotes in querystring values i.e

```
 <your-host>/?store=XXXXXX not like this <your-host>/?store='XXXXXX'
```

Also, `filter_by` is used for simple queries, If you want to make complex Queries use [filter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators) and for more info go through this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy)