# Why my SQLAlchemy query.flter works only on some attribute?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning SQLAlchemy of Python.

Below is an example I am useing.

First I generate a datafile contains puppy information like below:

```
class Puppy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'puppy'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String(6), nullable = False)
    dateOfBirth = Column(Date)
    shelter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('shelter.id'))
    weight = Column(Numeric(10))


male_names = ["Bailey", "Max", ...just some names..., "Luke", "Henry"]

female_names = ['Bella', 'Lucy', ...just some names..., 'Honey', 'Dakota']

def CreateRandomAge():
    today = datetime.today()
    days_old = randint(0,540)
    birthday = today - timedelta(days = days_old)
    return birthday

def CreateRandomWeight():
    return random.uniform(1.0, 40.0)

for i,x in enumerate(male_names):
    new_puppy = Puppy(name = x, gender = "male", dateOfBirth = CreateRandomAge(), weight= CreateRandomWeight())
    session.add(new_puppy)
    session.commit()

for i,x in enumerate(female_names):
    new_puppy = Puppy(name = x, gender = "female", dateOfBirth = CreateRandomAge(), weight= CreateRandomWeight())
    session.add(new_puppy)
    session.commit()
```

Now I want to filter some kinds of puppies as below:

```
testpuppy = session.query(Puppy).filter_by(name='Lucy')
print(testpuppy)

birthdate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=180)
smallpuppy = session.query(Puppy).filter_by(dateOfBirth < birthdate)
print(smallpuppy)
```

Then it is strange, because the testpuppy passed, I can get Lucy, but the dateofBirth can not pass, every time I want to get these smallpuppies, I just got an error

```
NameError: name 'dateOfBirth' is not defined
```

I really can not understand, why my filter can only be operated on some attribute, where is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use `filter` instead of `filter_by` like this:

```
smallpuppy = session.query(Puppy).filter(Puppy.dateOfBirth < birthdate)
```

For `filter`, the criterion should use `ClassName.propertyName` to access the column, and you can use `<` or `>`.

For `filter_by`, the criterion could be use `propertyName` directly to access the column, but you cannot use `<` or `>`.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy), it will give you more details about the difference between `filter` and `filter_by`.