# Why do I get NameError for the column that is defined in SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, nameerror

I am developing REST APIs with Flask. One of the tables is modeled as follows:

```
class AudioSessionModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'audio_session'
    id = db.Column('audio_session_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    cs_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    session_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    facility = db.Column(db.Integer)
    description = db.Column(db.String(400))

    def __init__(self, cs_id, session_id, facility):
        self.cs_id = cs_id
        self.session_id = session_id
        self.facility = facility
```

Business logics are defined in a DAO class:

```
class AudioSessionDAO(object):
    def update(self, data):
        audio = AudioSessionModel.query.filter(cs_id == data['CSID'], session_id == data['Session'])
        audio.description = data['Desc']
        db.session.commit()
        return audio
```

This `upate` function is called in my endpoint for `PUT` request:

```
@api.route('/OperatorAccessment')
class OperatorAssessment(Resource):

    @api.expect(assessment)
    def put(self):
        as_dao = AudioSessionDAO()
        as_dao.update(request.json)
```

The model `assessment` looks like this:

```
assessment = api.model('Operator Assessment', {
    'CSID': fields.Integer(required=True, description='Central Station ID'),
    'Session': fields.Integer(required=True, description='Session ID'),
    'Desc': fields.String(description='Description')
})
```

When I test the `PUT` request with the following json in request body:

```
{
   "CSID": 1,  
   "Session": 1, 
   "Desc": "Siren"
 }
```

I got the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx_app\model\dao.py", line 63, in update
    audio = AudioSessionModel.query.filter(cs_id == data['CSID'], session_id == data['Session'])
NameError: name 'cs_id' is not defined
```

Apparently, `cs_id` is defined. Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the attributes of the class, i.e.

```
AudioSessionModel.query.filter(
    AudioSessionModel.cs_id == data['CSID'],
    AudioSessionModel.session_id == data['Session'])
```

Or `filter_by` with keyword arguments using just `=`:

```
AudioSessionModel.query.filter_by(
    cs_id=data['CSID'],
    session_id=data['Session'])
```

See [What's the difference between filter and filter_by in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy)