# Why is there a NameError from SQLAlchemy when filtering?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do the following in Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM UserRecipe
WHERE
  user_id == 3
 AND
  status != 'donotshow'
```

This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(url=url).first_or_404()
userrecipes = UserRecipe.query.filter(user_id==user.id, status!='donotshow').with_entities(UserRecipe.recipe_id)
```

I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined
```

Would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get NameError for the column that is defined in SQLAlchemy model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223179/why-do-i-get-nameerror-for-the-column-that-is-defined-in-sqlalchemy-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`filter(*criterion)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) you need to qualify the column attributes with the class name:

```
userrecipes = UserRecipe.query.filter(UserRecipe.user_id==user.id, 
    UserRecipe.status!='donotshow').with_entities(UserRecipe.recipe_id)
```

By contrast, [`filter_by(**kwargs)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) accepts unqualified column attributes as keyword arguments:

```
userrecipes = UserRecipe.query.filter_by(user_id==user.id, 
    status!='donotshow').with_entities(UserRecipe.recipe_id)
```