# How to use order by in flask sqlalchemy for date attribute

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application and I am using flask sqlalchemy.I have two classes like below:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    diaries = db.relationship('Diary', backref='author', lazy=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"


class Diary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    diary_date= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
    emotion = db.Column(db.String(10))
    note = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Diary('{self.diary_date}', '{self.emotion}','{self.note}')"
```

I want to order by using diary_date and then take first seven records.I want to show frequent emotion in a week to user.For order by I used following query:

```
>>> records=(db.session.query(Diary).filter_by(Diary.user_id=User.id).join(Diary
,User.diaries).order_by(Diary.diary_date))
```

It is giving an error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Is the query wrong?Can you suggest a better query? I am new to sqlalchemy sorry if the question is too dumb.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: change `filter_by(Diary.user_id=User.id)` to `filter(Diary.user_id == User.id)`.

Comment: Still giving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `filter_by` to `filter` and replace `=` with `==`. It will resolve your error:

```
db.session.query(Diary).filter(Diary.user_id==User.id).join(Diary,User.diaries).order_by(Diary.diary_date)
```

And this gives you:

```
SELECT diary.id AS diary_id, diary.diary_date AS diary_diary_date, diary.emotion AS diary_emotion, diary.note AS diary_note, diary.user_id AS diary_user_id 
FROM user JOIN diary ON user.id = diary.user_id 
WHERE diary.user_id = user.id ORDER BY diary.diary_date
```

But as you can see `WHERE diary.user_id = user.id` is unnecessary as it is covered by `JOIN` expression. It can be safely removed.

---

Also you can change `default=datetime.now()` to `default=datetime.now`. Thanks to that `diary_date` will be set to time the `Diary` object is created and not when `Diary` was parsed by interpreter (all objects would get the same default time).

Comment: Thanks it worked.:) But how do you view those records in db itself?

Comment: You can just print your query (before calling `.all()`) If you want query with db specific dialect you can look at http://nicolascadou.com/blog/2014/01/printing-actual-sqlalchemy-queries/