# Using filter_by does not work as expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the count of categories in item_name using this script below

```
db.session.query(func.count(Garden.id).label('count'),Garden.item_name).group_by(Garden.item_name).all()
```

Works like a charm, but I need to filter this by specifying another condition, which I am not able to get it right. But I tried this script below.

```
db.session.query(func.count(Garden.id).label('count'),Garden.item_name).group_by(Garden.item_name).filter_by(Garden.item_type='vegetable').all()
```

i am trying to include item_type specific condition. But, I am making some mistake that I get an error. I am also aware its not how we add filter and group by at the same time. Can anyone post your solution?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.

```
db.session.query(func.count(Garden.id).label('count'),Garden.item_name).filter(Garden.item_type=="vegetable").group_by(Garden.item_name).all()
```