# Flask SQLalchemy filter integer list

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

Currently trying to implement a recommender system for games but I'm having some problems on the REST-API with flask/sqlalchemy

I've successfully implemented routes for retrieving games and trying to apply more filters. I want to filter the retrieved games by genres - which works when I'm filtering by a single genre id - the problem arises when I try to filter by multiple genres.

The route should look like /games?genres=3,7,8

The database has a Game and a Genre table and there is a one to many relationship between them, so one game is linked to multiple genres.

This is the Game db.Model

```
game_genres = db.Table('game_genres',
                       db.Column('game_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                           'games.id'), primary_key=True),
                       db.Column('genre_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                           'genres.id'), primary_key=True),
                       db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('game_id', 'genre_id')
                       )

game_platforms = db.Table('game_platforms',
                          db.Column('game_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                              'games.id'), primary_key=True),
                          db.Column('platform_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                              'platforms.id'), primary_key=True),
                          db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('game_id', 'platform_id')
                          )

class Game(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'games'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    genres = db.relationship(
        'Genre',
        secondary=game_genres,
        lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('genres', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete')
    )
    platforms = db.relationship(
        'Platform',
        secondary=game_platforms,
        lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('games', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete')
    )

    def __init__(self, title: str):
        self.title = title

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Game {self.title}>'

    @property
    def to_json(self):
        genres = []
        for genre in self.genres:
            genres.append(genre.to_json)
        platforms = []
        for platform in self.platforms:
            platforms.append(platform.to_json)
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'description': self.description,
            'year': self.year,
            'genres': genres,
            'platforms': platforms,
        }
    @classmethod
    def return_all(self, offset, limit):
        return {'games': [g.to_json for g in self.query.order_by(Game.id).offset(offset).limit(limit).all()]}

    @classmethod
    def return_bygenres(self, offset, limit, genres2):
        return {'games': [g.to_json for g in self.query\
                         .join(Game.genres, aliased=True)\
                         .filter(or_(*[id.like(gid)for gid in genres2])).all().order_by(Game.id).offset(offset).limit(limit).all()]}
```

This is the corresponding Genre Model

```
class Genre(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "genres"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Genre {self.name}>'

    @property
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
        }
```

The routes look like this

```
GAME_PARSER = reqparse.RequestParser()
GAME_PARSER.add_argument('offset', type=int)
GAME_PARSER.add_argument('limit', type=int)
GAME_PARSER.add_argument('genres')


class AllGames(Resource):
    def get(self):
        args = GAME_PARSER.parse_args()
        offset = 0 if args.offset is None else args.offset
        limit = 100 if args.limit is None else args.limit
        genres = args.genres
        return Game.return_bygenres(offset, limit, genres.split(","))
```

I've found the current query on a different post but it throws an error.
The error I'm getting is "'buildtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'like'"

I've tried different other ways, like using any, has, or in function but all of them return the above error.

Using  `self.query.join(Game.genres, aliased=True).filter_by(id==1).order_by(Game.id).offset(offset).limit(limit).all()` works in returning only games that have the genre-id 1

I'm not sure if I make a mistake in the query or the model is not implemented properly for that kind of query.

This is my first time coding with flask and sqlalchemy so I would appreciate any form of input!

Answer (score 1):

Methods `filter` and `filter_by` take different types of arguments. Please refer to this question/answers ['Difference between filter and filter_by in SQLAlchemy
'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128558/2800058) for an explanation.

As your `Genre` `id` field is an integer I would use the [`in_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_) operator to filter on this field. e.g.

```
@classmethod
def return_bygenres(self, offset, limit, genres2):
    # genres2 must be a list of integers, coerce if neccassary, e.g.
    # .filter(Genre.id.in_([int(s) for s in genres2]))

    _query = self.query\
            .join(Game.genres, aliased=True)\
            .filter(Genre.id.in_(genres2))\
            .order_by(Game.id)\
            .offset(offset)\
            .limit(limit)\
    return {'games': [g.to_json for g in _query.all()]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm getting an error with this query: name 'Genre' is not defined
I'm not quite sure why - Genre is a defined db.model although it's in another file - can this be the problem? that it can't make the link to the other file?