# how to user BETWEEN clause in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

my Model is

```
class RidesModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "rides"

ride_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

start_address = db.Column(db.String())
end_address = db.Column(db.String())
ride_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
ride_by = db.Column(db.String(), db.ForeignKey("users.email"), nullable=False)
ride_created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)


@classmethod
def find_by_email(cls, _email: str) -> "RidesModel":
    return cls.query.filter_by(ride_by=_email).all()

@classmethod
def find_between_dates(cls, _email: str, dt1, dt2) -> "RidesModel":
    return cls.query.filter_by(
            ride_by=_email,
            ride_datetime.between(dt1, dt2)

    ).all()
```

the mthod `find_by_email` works fine but `find_between_dates` give an error
this does not work. I get error in the console

```
m_rides.py", line 42
    ride_datetime.between(dt1, dt2)
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

and pyCharm says `"Positional argument after keyword argument"`

Could someone please help me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "between" clause or with sqlalchemy.  The problem is with the Python syntax in the call to `cls.query.filter_by(ride_by=_email, ride_datetime.between(dt1, dt2))`. See the duplicated question

Comment: I tried swapping the arguments, it doesn't work :(
It says an unresolved reference ride_datetime

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy