# How to use OR condition along with filter_by in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, conditional-statements

What is the equivalent of

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
db.session.query(User).filter(or_(User.email=='useremail@example.com', User.name=="username"))
```

using filter_by?

Basically how to write OR condition using **filter_by** rather than filter in sqlalchemy?

Comment: what's the problem with filter() ?

Comment: you may wwant to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: I want to use keyword arguments, hence the q
like ,
conditions={'email':'sk@asdf.com','name':'asdf'}
db.session.query(User).filter_by(or(**conditions))