# flasksqlalchemy query multiple parameter with startwith and paginate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
i am trying to query multiple parameter with startswith and other parameter and pagination in flask.
```

`results_of_search = Course.query.filter(Course.title.startswith(search_data)).paginate(per_page=9)`

this query is giving me the correct result but i want to add other filters as well
`results_of_search =  Course.query.filter(Course.title.startswith(search_data),university=current_user.uni).paginate(per_page=9)`

i have tried searching everywhere

Comment: And what is your error? Or you don't have an error, but results are not what you expected? For me the problem is not clear. Provide your sqlalchemy model and example query arguments values.

Comment: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'university' but i have the field university on my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed syntax of `filter` and `filter_by` methods. For `filter` method there should be also model name before attribute name, and you should use `==`, instead od `=`:

```py
Course.query.filter( 
   Course.title.startswith(search_data),
   Course.university == current_user.uni
).paginate(per_page=9)
```

Here is a topic about differences between `filter` and `filter_by`: [Difference between filter and filter_by in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy)