# TypeError: Query.filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'login' running Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm new to Flask, and getting an TypeError: Query.filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'login'.
I'm using flask-login addon. Here is my model.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

My route:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_login():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    if login and password:
        user = User.query.filter(login=login).first()  # this line causes an error

        if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)
            next_page = request.args.get('next_page')
            redirect(next_page)
        else:
            flash("Login or password is incorrect")
    else:
        flash("Please fill login and password fields")
        return render_template('login.html')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you meant to use `filter_by` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128558/4727702) for more info.

Comment: Just use "==", instead of "="

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your query syntax
use

```
user = User.query.filter_by(login=login).first()
```

or

```
user = User.query.filter_by(login=login).one()
```